# if a curve $A=\{z : |z-3|+|z+3|=8\}$ and $B=\{z : |z-3|=k\},\; k\in \mathbb R^+$ touch the curve $A$ internally, then which are correct

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections, hyperbolic-geometry

if a curve $A=\{Z : |Z-3|+|Z+3|=8\}$ and $B=\{Z : |Z-3|=k\},\; k\in \mathbb R^+$ touches the curve $A$ internally, and given another curve $C = \bigl\{Z : \bigl||Z-3|-|Z+3|\bigr|=4\bigr\},\;$ where $Z$ denotes complex number $x+iy$. Then

(A)  $A$ and $C$ intersect orthogonally and $k=1$'

(B) $k=1$

(C) $k=\dfrac{3}{2}$

(D) $B$ touches $C$ internally.

**My Approach:**

Curve $A$ is ellipse given by $\dfrac{x^2}{16}+\dfrac{y^2}{7}=1\;$ and curve $B$ is circle given by $(x-3)^2+y^2=k^2$.

Since both curve are touching each other so i solved both curve together and Put discriminant equal to $0$

**Steps:**   $\dfrac{x^2}{16}+\dfrac{k^2-(x-3)^2}{7}=1$

$\implies\;\;7x^2+16(k^2-(x-3)^2)=112$

$\implies\;\; 9x^2-96x+(256-16k^2)=0$

Now I made discriminant  $D=0$ because both curve are touching each other.

Above equation give me $k=0$.

But after verifying from **Desmos** $k=1$ is solution and i know how to do it graphically.

**My Doubt:**

$1.$ What is going wrong in my method

This problem is same as [A problem on confocal conics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157544/a-problem-on-confocalconics) but in this problem OP's Doubt is different.

Comment: Setting a quadratic discriminant equal zero is not a general way to produce tangent curves. Sometimes it's part of a method based on the number of solutions, but making sure that helps involves more than just that one step.

Comment: Two curves touch at a point $P$ if they intersect at $P$ at which they have a common tangent line. You have to find the slopes of two tangent lines and let them equal.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly detailed explanation of the answer given by @aschepler in the comments:

Let the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfying $\frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{y^2}{7} = 1$ be denoted by $E$, let the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfying $(x-3)^2 + y^2 = k$ be $C$, and also let the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfying $\frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{k^2 - (x-3)^2}{7} = 1$ be denoted by $T$.

Now suppose you have given that $C$ touches $E$ internally. Assuming that $C$ and $E$ have no other points of intersection, it implies that $C \cap E$ has exactly one point in $\mathbb{R}^2$. However $C \cap E \neq T$, rather $(x,y) \in C \cap E \Rightarrow (x,y) \in T$, which means that $C \cap E \subseteq T$.
So the fact that any equation representing $C \cap E$ must have exactly one distinct real root, does not imply that the equation representing $T$ must have one real root. So you can't set the discriminant of the quadratic to zero, because that quadratic may have more than one root.

**What is the way to solve it then?**

Let $C \cap E$ be the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfying $\frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{y^2}{7} = 1 \land y^2 = k^2 - (x-3)^2$. Now suppose $x_1(k)$ and $x_2(k)$ are roots of $\frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{k^2 - (x-3)^2}{7} = 1$, and their corresponding $y$ values got from $y^2 = k^2 - (x-3)^2$ be $\pm y_1(k)$ and $\pm y_2(k)$. So your **possible** solutions to $T'$ are $(x_1(k), \pm y_1(k))$ and $(x_2(k), \pm y_2(k))$. Now substituting them back in $\frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{y^2}{7} = 1$, for each of the 4 points you will get a value of $k$ for which that point is a solution of $C \cap E$.

This method is quite ugly and doesn't generalize very well, but I'm curious to see a generic criterion for exactly one point of intersection of two conics.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $P(x_0,y_0)$ is the intersection of $A$ and $B$. Suppose $y_0\neq0$. Then the slope of the tangent of $A$ at $P$ is
$$ m_A=-\frac{7x_0}{16y_0} $$
and the slope of the tangent of $B$ at $P$ is
$$ m_B=-\frac{x_0-3}{y_0}. $$
Since $A$ and $B$ touch at $P$, one has
$$ -\frac{7x_0}{16y_0}=-\frac{x_0-3}{y_0} $$
which gives
$$ x_0=\frac{16}{3}. $$
But $P_0$ is on $A$ which implies
$$ \frac{x_0^2}{16}+\frac{y_0^2}{7}=1. $$
This equation doesn't have real solution. Thus $y_0=0$ and hence $x_0=4$ and $k=1$.